# phpmailer reply-to not working when reply from mobile app

Tags: phpmailer

I'm using phpmailer on my ERP and the from email is a noreply@ and the reply-to is my client/company email.
Everything is working, however, I noticed that when a person is replying by a mobile app the reply goes to the "from" email and not the reply-to, also, that happens to the autoresponse.
How can I solve the problem?
This is part of the code

```
    $mail->setFrom($from, $name_from);
    $mail->addAddress(getToEmail($iduser));
    $mail->ClearReplyTos();
    $mail->addReplyTo($reply, "Reply to " . $name_from);
    $mail->isSMTP();  
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
    $mail->Port = 465;
    $mail->Sender = $reply;
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body = $message;
```

Comment: This is not the case for me on iOS 14.5. If a reply-to is set, that's where replies go. Perhaps your issue is elsewhere?

Comment: I tried with my smartphone with gmail app and it's working well but sometimes I have reply in the noreply@ inbox from iOS but I don't know which version and which application they use.

Comment: One thing to know that might be related, though I don't know if reply-to does it – many email clients ignore the from *name* that's actually in the message, and instead show the name that was first used with that address.

Answer (score 0):

one more thing, I was told that mobile clients not always download the entire email but show a button to do so. These clients cannot see "reply-to" if the mail is not fully downloaded.

I am not sure if this is fully true ...